# TFS 2013 Build Agent target .NET version

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild

I installed a TFS 2013 and configured the build service, but I am trying to build an old application that was written on .NET 2.0. Each time I run the build I receive this error:

```
<link-to-file> (24): Reference required to assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' containing the base class 'System.Web.UI.Control'. Add one to your project.
```

I checked and on the server there is installed .NET 2.0 version.
My question is how to change the build definition to target another version of the framework, because my guess is that the version is incorrect, but I can't find where to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [the `/ToolsVersion` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx) you'll need to go in to the Advanced settings of your build process and add the switch as an MSBuild argument.

`/ToolsVersion:2.0`